# Whis is the usage of powerline font?

Tags: fonts, github

Today I stumble upon this repository in github

[Lokaltog / powerline-fonts](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts)

There isn't much information related to what is does/patched to those fonts. I did google search for it but nothing is found. Does anyone know what is it?

Comment: Seven years later, and there's _still_ really no page you can deliver someone to that provides a good, targeted answer to the simple question, "WTF are Powerline symbols, and why would I care if a font has them?" To the point where _this q&a_ is still one of the better explainers out there. (If it had some screenshots it'd be perfect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts

> "This repository contains pre-patched and adjusted fonts for usage
>   with the new Powerline plugin."

======

https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

> Powerline is a statusline plugin for vim, and provides statuslines and
>   prompts for several other applications, including zsh, bash, tmux,
>   IPython, Awesome and Qtile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am still confused about what is actually patched for the font. What is the problem for using unpatched font in powerline?

Comment: Per https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fontpatching.html#font-patching -- "Powerline provides a font patcher for custom glyphs like the segment dividers (arrows), branch symbol, padlock symbol, etc. " (There is also a note that some Linux users may not have to use the patches.) This means that the patches add symbols to standard fonts, related to how Powerline displays. The appropriate patch would be applied for whatever font you prefer to have Powerline use. There are symbols that Powerline uses for its display that are not included in a standard font character set.

Comment: oops, so actually they added those symbols into the font! Thanks man